# SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'haystack' at row 2

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data using mysql find_in_set the find in set contains around 180 , separated values

The query which i used for demo

```
SELECT 'id' AS column_name, 10 AS header_name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT( '',T.row_id) SEPARATOR  ', ') AS err_rows FROM `tmp_import_table_1595858629` T WHERE T.is_removed=0 AND (LENGTH(T.column26) > 0 AND T.column26 IS  NOT NULL AND T.column26 != '') AND FIND_IN_SET(T.column26,'204,273,453,1050,1125,1153,1206,1889,2198,2209,2212,2214,2216,2217,2219,2220,2221,2222,2223,2224,2225,2226,2227,2228,2230,2231,2232,2234,2235,2236,2237,2239,2240,2241,2242,2243,2244,2245,2246,2247,2248,2249,2250,2251,2252,2253,2254,2256,2258,2259,2260,2261,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268,2269,2270')
```

This ends with error

```
SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'haystack' at row 2
```

Comment: Can you restructure this to be properly relational? You're asking for trouble when using comma-separated values.

Comment: This is from the single table

Comment: I can see that, and I'm just observing how that's the source of a lot of pain and misery because this database is not relational.

Comment: You could try increasing group concat length. `SET session group_concat_max_len=10000;` Then exexute this and your query together.